# Rails tags for all Photos in an Album

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I have an Album and a Photo model.  Photos have tags via Acts As Taggable On.

Is there a nice Rails'y way to get a list of all the tags contained within an Album?   Eg, one combined list of tags of all the photos inside one particular Album?

I know I could grab the Album, iterate its Photos and grabs the tags and then dedupe it but just wondering if there is a much nicer, cleaner, more efficient way to achieve this?

Neil

Answer (score -1):

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :photos
  has_many :tags, through: :photos
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please could you elaborate a bit with how I can actually get what I was querying about.  I'm a bit confused with how to get from what you posted to what I am aiming to get back as a result.

Comment: @rctneil Please share your code and models so I can update my answer.

Comment: Generally my idea was to use `through:` option somehow.